# How to figure out if something is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $S$ be the set of all zero divisors in $R$.

Is $S$ an ideal of $R$?

Also, Let $U(R)$ be the set of all units in $R$. IS $U(R)$ an ideal of $R$?

So I know for a subring $I$ of a ring $R$ it is called an ideal of $R$ if for every $r$ in $R$ and every $a$ in $I$ both $ra$ and $ar$ are in $I$, but I don't know how this applies to showing that these things are in I. I don't know how to show every $ra$ is in $I$ because you're not given a specific ring.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: You don't have to know what the ring is. Take a zero divisor $s \in S$. If you take any other element of your ring, say $r$, is $rs$ necessarily a zero divisor? (The answer is yes. Can you tell me the element that makes it zero?)

Comment: @MikePierce zero?

Comment: Not zero. The definition of a zero divisor, say $s$, is that there exists a **non-zero** element, call it $t$, such that $st = 0$. Imagine the elements $2$ and $3$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Answer (score 2):

<s>The set of all zero divisors is an ideal :</s>

Take any $s\in S$ and $r\in R$. Since $s$ is a zero divisor, there exists $t\in S$  such that $s\cdot t = 0$. Then $(r\cdot s)\cdot t = r\cdot (s\cdot t)=r\cdot 0 = 0$. Hence $r\cdot s$ is also a zero divisor.

Now take $s,t\in S$. We want to show that $s+t\in S$. Say $s\cdot s'=t\cdot t'=0$. We know they exist since $s$ and $t$ are zero divisors. Then $(s+t)\cdot s'\cdot t' = (s\cdot s')\cdot t' + (t\cdot t')\cdot s' = 0\cdot t' + 0\cdot s' = 0$. Hence $s+t$ is a zero divisor, i.e. $s+t\in S$.

Hence $S$ is an ideal.

The set of units $U$ cannot be an ideal because it does not contain $0$. Note that every ideal $I$ necessarily contains $0$. One could argue whether $U\cup \{0\}$ is an ideal. This is also not generally true (except the case $R$ is a field, in this case this set is all $R$) because if there exists a nonunit nonzero element $t\in R$ then $t\cdot u$ cannot be unit for any $0\neq u\in U$ (if $t\cdot u\cdot v = 1$ then $t\cdot (u\cdot v)=1$, i.e. $t$ is a unit. This argument also shows that why it is an ideal iff $R$ is a field.

Edit : The above argument is false because of the example of 1ENİGMA1. Note that I did not notice that it is possible to have $s'\cdot t'=0$ so $s+t$ may not be a zero divisor. Hence you can say this : $S$ is an ideal iff $S$ is closed under addition. I keep this answer anyway so maybe there are things that you can use here.

Comment: I think it would be nice to somehow visually indicate that the proof is wrong in the beginning of the post, to prevent confusion. Or, better, reformulate it, and/or mark the place where it fails.

Comment: I am trying to strike out the argument but I did not achieve it :)

Comment: If $R$ is local then we can say the set of all zero divisors is an ideal.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right.

Answer (score 1):

it is not an ideal. Take $R=\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$. The elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are zero divisors but their sum is not zero divisors.

For second question: $U(R)$ is not  an ideal.
Hint:$R=\mathbb{Z_6}$ with $U(\mathbb{Z_6})=\{1,3,5\}$